# Computation of KO theory of a point

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I have some basic questions about real K-theory (I mean $KO$-theory).

**Question 1:** I have seen the table
$$
KO^{-i}(\mathrm{pt})=
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z},& i=0\\
\mathbb{Z}_2,& i=1\\
\mathbb{Z}_2,& i=2\\
0,& i=3\\
\mathbb{Z},& i=4\\
0,& i=5\\
0,& i=6\\
0,& i=7\\
\end{cases}
$$
in various places, for example on p. 15 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.08001.pdf), but haven't been able to find a reference where this is computed explicitly. Where could I find such a reference?

**Question 2:** What is the reason for using the negative indices $-i$, as opposed to $i$, for keeping track of the $KO$ groups?

**Question 3:** Can $KO^0(\mathrm{pt})$ be thought of as the path components of Fredholm operators, i.e. $\pi_0(\mathcal{F})$, where $\mathcal{F}$ are the Fredholm operators on a real Hilbert space? If so, is there a similar meaning in these terms for higher $i$?

Comment: Bott-periodicity

Comment: To explain that previous comment a little more, which is for Question 1, it's to do with the homotopy groups of $\mathbb{Z}\times BO(\infty) = \mathbb{Z}\times \mathrm{colim}_nB O(n)$, which, IIRC, is a classifying space for $KO$.

Comment: Q1: Atiyah's paper "Clifford modules" (https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/abs.pdf) is a good reference.  I also explained the calculation in Section 7.2 of my thesis (https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/research/thesis.pdf).  There is nothing significantly original there, but you might or might not find the exposition useful.

Comment: Behrens's paper "A new proof of the Bott periodicity theorem" is another source for Q1. https://www3.nd.edu/~mbehren1/papers/bott.pdf .

Comment: If I recall correctly, I think there's also a nice computation of this in Milnor's book on Morse Theory.

Comment: @GregoryArone For real Bott periodicity he has a follow up paper clarifying and simplifying certain sections: https://www3.nd.edu/~mbehren1/papers/addendum.pdf

Comment: I answered Qu 1 here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192316/the-periodic-values-in-bott-periodicity/193353#193353

Answer (score 3):

I have only answers for the first two questions.

Starting from the second one.
Naturally you can define only $KO^{-i}(X)$. Namely, $KO^{-i}(X) \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} KO^0(\Sigma^i X)$. And the standard way to define $KO^{i}(X)$ is the Bott periodicity.

As a reference to $KO^{-i}(pt)$ there is a nice book ``Algebraic topology -- homotopy and homology'' by R. Switzer. Chapter 11 contains the required computations.